# How can we get the date of when product came in stock in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, stock

I need to get the date when did product came in to stock in Magento 2. Please help

or How can I write event when product came in stock and store that date in database?

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not have this info

Comment: Not even pragmatically ?

Comment: yes, this data is not stored in db. So, you can write own module that add this data in db and than use it

Comment: Can you please tell me in which table magento 2 store stock date ?